# CodeIgniter: How can I use xss_clean function of security class inside a library?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to call the xss_clean function of the security class inside my library. Here is what I'm using:

```
array_map('$this->CI->security->xss_clean', $shipping_info);
```

`$shipping_info` is an array. 
`CI` is my global CodeIgniter object that I instantiated in my constructor: `$this->CI =& get_instance();`

Here is the php error:

```
array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 
        '$this->CI->security->xss_clean' not found or invalid function name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
array_map(array($this->CI->security, 'xss_clean'), $shipping_info);
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! Do you mind explaining your answer a little more?